# php storm yellow highlight code - how to remove this?

Tags: phpstorm

Im searching the web, and searching inside phpstorm 8 but i can not find this annoying yellow highlight. Wh is it there and how can i remove this?

schreenshot [image]

Comment: possibly under code smell

Comment: Please try `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE. If nothing: please provide the whole file and state your exact IDE version and build number.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the result of "quick search" (ctrl+f) - it supports multiline search so it is possible to accidentally copy big part of file into a clipboard and then paste it into search. I just checked on my PHPStorm and it was quite easy to reproduce similar effect.